# Encoding with tinker and Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to use tinker to manipulate the tables of my project, so, the first problem I'm having is that i have created a utf8 encoded database, and after that, i run my migrations, then, the tables that are created are using utf8mb4_unicode_ci. Shouldn't they be utf8 by default? If yes, how do I change that?

The second problem is that when I try to insert words on my local language (brazilian portuguese) on a table, using tinker, im getting an error caused by these characters. Like this:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xA1tulo ...' for column 'title' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `posts` (`title`, `body`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Título 1, Corpo do primeiro post, 2017-10-09 14:58:40, 2017-10-09 14:58:40))'
```

Do I have to make tinker accept my local language or do I have to make any enconding change on the project?

My **post** migration code:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            // $table->charset = 'utf8';
            // $table->collation = 'utf8_general_ci';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->mediumText('body');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('posts');
    }
}
```

On tinker I'm doing this:

```
$post = new App\post();
$post->title = 'Título 1';
$post->body = 'Corpo do primeiro post';
$post->save();
```

This is the first time that I'm using Laravel, so I'm kinda lost.

Comment: can you please show as the your code so we can help

Comment: Hi, I edit the question with the code of my Post migration and what I'm doing on Tinker.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding these lines to your 'config/database.php' file and try again.

```
'charset'   => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci'
```

Comment: That solved the collation of my tables. Now, only the migrations table is still using the utf8mb4_unicode_ci enconding. The tinker enconding problem continues.